# How to install VNC server which uses USB Dongle

Tags: windows, vnc, vncserver

I have a computer which has Mobile Broadband Connection to connect to the internet (USB Dongle).. I want to monitor that computer installing VNC Server... Is it Possible to install VNC and Monitor in a Mobile Broadband Environment.? I am using Windows 7 & Huawei USB Dongle.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Could you clarify what you mean by 'Is it Possible to install VNC and Monitor in a Mobile Broadband Environment.?' ? Also please add if you are using Windows or Linux (and which version). You can edit your question to answer these questions so other people don't have to go through the comments.

Comment: Means, How to connect to VNC Server of the Remote Machine in Mobile Broadband Environment (Dynamic IP). I think by using public IP, able to access that computer. I saw that VNC requires Port Forwarding. But I couldn't find a way to forward port in a USB Dongle. - @mtak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a USB dongle which behaves as a network interface in Windows, you should be able to see it running `ipconfig /all` using `cmd.exe` (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>).

If this is the case, you don't need port forwarding and you can immediately connect to the VNC server on the IP address you got from `ipconfig /all` (provided you opened Windows firewall to open TCP port 5900).

If you see an RFC1918 address (192.168.x.x or  10.x.x.x) it is possible you got this from the dongle or from your operator. If you got the IP from your operator there is not much you can do, and this is not going to work using port forwarding. You could try a workaround using TeamViewer or VPN software such as Hamachi.

Comment: Is there a way to VNC server to listen to an vps and (using dedicated ip) and view what is happening? something like that? even I Have not much idea with VPN.

Comment: Seems like a different question. You can ask a new question by using the "Ask Question" button on the top right.